# What do we need to install for developing with JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I want to use and learn JavaCV. 
•   So, I read some articles about how to set up JavaCV development environment in Window 7. At first they download and install OpenCV and adding some directory paths to System Variable, After that ,they extract javacv-0.7-bin.zip and javacv-0.7-cppjars.zip packages to somewhere(probably C:)  and add some .jar files to their projects.

**My Question :** Do I need to install OpenCV for developing in JavaCV? because I wrote some JavaCV programs and my JavaCV programs compile and run properly (without installing OpenCV).

Answer (score 1):

According to a javacv developer, the answer is NO. It comes bundled. Source: [javacv issue 406 on GitHub](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/406).